# Catch exception when class definition is not visible

Tags: c++, exception

I'm working on an issue whereby a corrupt input file is causing an exception to be thrown. The exception class is defined in an implementation file and thus not visible to me. It does inherit from `std::exception`.

I tried simply forward declaring the exception class, since I'm just catching it by reference. However, this gave me a `error: invalid use of incomplete type` compiler error (using GCC 6.2 on Linux). I suppose that the compiler needs the full exception object type so that it can rethrow the exception if needed.

So this is what I'd like to do:

```
// library.cpp

namespace FOO {

struct SomeException : public std::exception
{
    // string member, virtual dtor, ctor taking one arg and virtual what()
};

void doStuff() {
}

}


// my main.cpp
namespace FOO
{
   struct SomeException;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        FOO::doStuff();
    }
    catch (FOO::SomeException& e)
    {
        // ignore e, but I know where it came from so log
        // an appropriate message
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        // most other exceptions, log `what()` message
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        // tell user to contact customer support
    }
}
```

Just printing the `what()` message isn't appropriate to my context.

I could ask the other team to move their exception class definition into a header. That will probably be a slow process. I suppose I could also do a string comparison on the `what()` message, but that seems ugly.

Are there any other options?

(BTW I can't see any mention of this via Google, but this does seem to be a sort of anti-pattern, the "throw-only exception").

Comment: I would say this is a design error on the part of whoever implemented that exception. Seems like the correct course of action would be to request that they fix it.

Comment: You are dealing with a broken/buggy library and should demand it to be fixed. A definition of any exception propagated to the user code must be visible to the user code. Forward-declaring it won't help, because you can't access an object using forward declaration (and I presume you need to access this object, otherwise, why would you catch it)?

Comment: @Francois This is what I was afraid people would say.

Comment: If they can be persuaded to change it, they probably should. If not ... yes, catching by reference is the right way to do it - but you could potentially catch by pointer, in which case you shouldn't need the class definition, and the forward define ought to be enough, I think. You will have the problem of who owns the exception, and should therefore delete it - and the problem of object slicing if it's you, and they haven't implemented virtual destructors. All things considered, getting them to change it is best.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't need to access the exception object at the moment. I just want to be able to catch it to be able to log a message that is more specific than 'something went wrong'.

Comment: Indeed, they should provide the header for the exception class.

Comment: @Rags I have access to the throw site source (but not the rights to make SCM changes). The exception class gets thrown by value. I think I'm seeing a strong consensus here.

Comment: Can you temporarily copy paste exception class into your code?

Comment: @ks1322 do you mean the example code I gave here or in my main.cpp?

Comment: I mean that you could move exception class definition into a header yourself and place it somewhere in your code so that not to wait for other team to do it (you say that it is a slow process). When other team does it, you could begin using their exception class definition and delete yours copy.

Comment: @ks1322 I could but I'd rather avoid ODR violations. I'll try to find out how long it will take to get the lib changed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the original class, you won't be able to catch it correctly:

> C++ standard / [except.handle]:
>
> The *exception-declaration* in a *handler* describes the type(s) of
>   exceptions that can cause that *handler* to be entered.
>   The *exception-declaration* shall not denote an incomplete type, an abstract class type, or an rvalue reference type.
>   The *exception-declaration* shall not denote a pointer or reference to an incomplete type, other than [*cv* void*].

So there's no ideal and clean solution.  But maybe an acceptable work-around: a class derived from [std::exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) is polymorphic.  So you could consider using [`typeid()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) (eventually in conjunction with [`type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index)) to identify the real type in the `catch (std::exception& e)` block.

IMHO, it should be an acceptable way to differentiate between unknown exceptions when `.what()` is not an alternative.  The inconvenience is however that the value of `type_info` data (eg. `typeid(e).name()`) is not defined in the standard, which makes any hard-coded value non portable.

Proof of concept:

```
//somewhere
class MyExcept : public std::exception { };

...

// somewhere else
try {
    throw std::exception();
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout <<"case 1: " << typeid(e).name() << std::endl;
}

try {
    throw MyExcept();
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout <<"case 2: "<< typeid(e).name() << std::endl;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/52tQUU)

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I suspected. This looks like the best I can do until the lib gets changed.